# Free map api's to create my own mobile app

Tags: android, ios

I am creating gps navigation app for android and IOS. Could anybody please tell me which map api can i use for free of cost.

Best Regards,
PSP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use one of this:

1. [Google Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/)
2. [OpenLayers](http://openlayers.org/)
3. [Bing](http://www.microsoft.com/maps/developers/web.aspx)
4. [Nokia](http://developer.here.com/)
5. [LeafLet](http://leafletjs.com/)
6. [Modes Maps](http://modestmaps.com/)
7. [Polymaps](http://polymaps.org/)

Some of them have the restrictions to use for free - for exmpmle - not more than xxx transaction in a year.